# How to add dynamic objects into the nested array so that it will contain similar structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

Following are the samp test array[myTest] which are containing the two objects with the id one and id two.

Into the id one there is type and contains two another objects with key and value.
And into the id two there is type which contains only one object with key and value.

I want to add one another object into the id two same as id one my final out put would contains the same as id one.

Expected output ::

```js
var myTest = [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: [
        {
          key: "Change",
          value: "value"
        },
        {
          key: "Review",
          value: "value1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      type: [
        {
          key: "Change",
          value: "value"
        },
        {
          key: "Review",
          value: "anyvalue"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I tried using the following way but not luck

```js
var myTest = [{
    id: 1,
    type: [{
        key: "Change",
        value: "value"
      },
      {
        key: "Review",
        value: "value1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: [{
      key: "Change",
      value: "value"
    }]
  }
];


myTest.forEach(function(item, idx) {
  if (item.type) {
    item.type.map(function(it) {
      if (
        it.hasOwnProperty("key") &&
        it.key === "Change"
      ) {
        const isChange = it.key;
      } else {
        if (it.key !== "Review") {
          it["key"] = "Change";
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

console.log(myTest)
```

Comment: Don't use `map()` if the callback function doesn't return a value or you're not using the result. Use `forEach()`.

Comment: Also `{ const isChange = it.key; }` effectively doesn't do anything

Comment: Also, it's unclear where `"anyvalue"` is coming from, in your expected result

Comment: do you have the wanted pattern always at index zero or do you want to use `id`, but the array is not sorted?

Comment: you can't use `!=` to detect a *missing* object.

Comment: Is the missing key always `Review`, or do you have to copy all the keys and values that are in id 1 that aren't in id 2?

Answer (score 0):

You could get a temporary object and delete seen keys. Then add the values of the `temp` object.

```js
var myTest = [{ id: 1, type: [{ key: "Change", value: "value" }, { key: "Review", value: "value1" }] }, { id: 2, type: [{ key: "Change", value: "value" }] }];

for (let i = 1; i < myTest.length; i++) {
    const temp = Object.fromEntries(myTest[0].type.map(o => [o.key, { ...o }]));
    myTest[i].type.forEach(({ key }) => delete temp[key]);
    myTest[i].type.push(...Object.values(temp));
}

console.log(myTest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to add type to specific id of your collection:

```
/**
 * If Type key exist in types, then update its value, otherwise add new type
 * @param {Object[]} types Collection of Types
 * @param {string} key Type Key
 * @param {string} value Type Value
 */
function updateType(types, key, value) {
  let keyFound = false;
  let result = [...types];
  result.every((type) => {
    if (type.key === key) {
      keyFound = true;
      type.value = value;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  if (!keyFound) {
    result.push({
      key: key,
      value: value
    });
  }
  return result;
}

/*
 * Function will add collection type into the collection item of provided id. If type property not exists before, then it will set it implicitly.
 * @param {Object[]} collection - Object Array that consist of items by id
 * @param {number} id - Id of collection item
 * @param {Object} type - Key Value pair that you want to add in collection types
 */
function addType(collection, id, type) {
  let idFound = false;
  let result = [...collection];
  result.every((item) => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      idFound = true;
      if (!item.type || !Array.isArray(item.type)) {
        item.type = [];
      }
      item.type = updateType(item.type, type.key, type.value);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  if (!idFound) {
    result.push({
      id: id,
      type: [type]
    });
  }
  return result;
}

// Collection Defination
var myTest = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: [
      {
        key: "Change",
        value: "value"
      },
      {
        key: "Review",
        value: "value1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: [
      {
        key: "Change",
        value: "value"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// Adding new type in exisisting id
let withNewType = addType(myTest, 2, { key: "Review", value: "Review Value" });
// Updating type of exisisting id of specific key
let withUpdatedType = addType(withNewType, 2, {
  key: "Review",
  value: "Review UpdatedValue"
});
// Adding type to new id
let withNewId = addType(withUpdatedType, 3, { key: "Change", value: "Value1" });
console.log(withNewId);
```

**[Edit]**: Now you can add data item with dynamic id, update the value of existing type of specific key, or add new type to existing data item of specific id.

Comment: Here you have give the id as static,How can I give the dynamic id and pass in addType function ?

Comment: Check the updated solution. It will allow you to add data item of new id, update type of specific id and specific key data item, add new type to data item of specific id.